# What is the best approach to create aggregation tables?

Tags: java, aggregate, hsqldb

I have data being collected every 1 sec and stored in hsqlDB.
I need to have aggregation data (per 15 sec, 1 min etc) on each metrics in the data collected.
What is the best approach to calculate the aggregation values? When to store in the DB?
Should I calculate the values online and each 15 sec store in DB? Or maybe query the DB for the last results and calculate the aggregation on them? Should I use small aggregation (15 sec) to calculate the large aggregation (1 min) ?
Are there free java tools for it?

Answer (score 0):

From previous experience, I would suggest using a real time database, probably non-relational with a built-in ability to deal with time series. That way, you should be able to avoid storing calculated aggregated data. Using a relational database, you will quickly end up with millions of rows that will be difficult to manage and slow to access. Your other option is to denormalize your data and store every 1 hour of data in a single row, in a BLOB column (in binary format).

Comment: Hi, I do save the aggregation data as single row and most of it is BLOB format. Changing the DB currently is not an option. What I need more is the correct approach to do the aggregation process.

Comment: We had real time data stored in a modified Sybase database server. The vendor provided software, stored the raw data in separate tables than aggregated data. All on BLOBs though. When doing aggregations you should take into account problems you might have with rounding. Addition, multiplication are not associative and commutative when it comes to floating point arithmetics. As such, doing sum of sums might be a better idea that serially summing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use HSQLDB is MVCC mode for concurrent reads and writes.

Provided the table for the raw data has an indexed timestamp column, aggregate calculation on a range is very fast using a SELECT statement. Because SELECT statements with aggregate calculations happen concurrently, you can use separate threads to perform the operation every 1 second and every 15 seconds.

Comment: I actually have indexed timestamp index. Does hsqldb automatically supports MVCC or I need to implement it? Another thing, is that the data that needs to be aggregated is stored as BLOB.

Comment: MVCC is a setting in HSQLDB which you can choose. If your data is actually a blob, you need to extract the fields from it.